# Symfony plugin development

Tags: php, symfony1, paypal, symfony-1.4

Can anyone point me towards a good tutorial/documentation on writing symfony plugins?
I'm trying to write a plugin for paypal using doctrine and sf 1.4.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Jobeet tutorial has a section of turning the Jobeet application into a plugin which is very good.

http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/20

Comment: Thanks man, that was exactly what I was looking for, too bad I only looked at the tutorial through day 17. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There already exists a couple of plugins PayPal integration but I think most of them are for 1.0/1.2 and were never fully completed. Might be worth taking a look at them on the Symfony site.

And there's this: http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/FAQ

Comment: Yeah, I think that is the problem with symfony plugins, not many of them for the new version, I think that'll change in the future.